# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined for comments

Tags: node.js

I am creating a user profile section where comments on a blogsite from that user can be viewed. I am currently getting this error on this piece of code

```
<ul>
<% blogs.comments.forEach(function(blog) { %>
    <li><a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/comment_id</a></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

The GET request that brings user to page has the following code

```
router.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundUser) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
    Blog.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, blogs) {
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
      res.render("show", {user: foundUser, blogs: blogs});
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `blogs` object does not have property `comments`, check its existence before using it

```
<ul>
<% if (Array.isArray(blogs.comments)) { %>
  <% blogs.comments.forEach(function(blog) { %>
    <li><a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/comment_id</a></li>
  <% }); %>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that blogs.comments does not have a value or it is not an array.

Try doing a console log to check if is contains an array of values.

Comment: Add the variable on the previous route and got the error to move to the <li><a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/comment_id</a></li> but now it saying that it can't find blog as it undefined anything thoughts on how to get this completed?

Comment: where it says `blog._id`, that value is actually `comments[val]._id`.            
 Will this work? `<li><a href="/blogs/<%= blogs._id %>/comments/comment_id</a></li>`